# protobuf-maven-plugin does not generate java artifacts

Tags: maven-plugin, protobuf-java

I have below maven configuration and I am not able to figure out why java artifacts are not generated for my proto. My Proto file is in folder

> /src/main/proto/hello.proto

I see no errors in my console when I do

> mvn package

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.XXX.grpc</groupId>
  <artifactId>grpc-poc-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>grpc-poc-client</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
      <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
      <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
      <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0.Final</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>0.5.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <clearOutputDirectory>false</clearOutputDirectory>
            <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.4.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
            <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
            <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.7.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>compile-custom</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

I am following the sample from 
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-grpc-java/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#2

Comment: Did you manage to get it working? I am facing the same issue